# Google Translation in react-native

Tags: react-native, google-api, google-translate, google-cloud-ml

I have made a react-native application in which text gets translated into a specified language. But now I am stuck. What I want is if someone types in the input text then by using the keyboard space bar the input text will get translated. How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can approach this is to check the ASCII value of each charecter when user enters data. Use the onChangeText props of TextInput to get the value of text input as soon as value is entered. With each text entered, convet the value to its ASCII value using charCodeAt() function provided by Javascript and check it with the ASCII value of space key, which is 32.

If it is 32, then split your entered string with spaces to get an array of words using split function of javascript, get the last word from the array, and send that to google-traslate api if you only need word by word meaning. If you need whole paragraph meaning, you do not need to split the array, just send whole text until now to google-translate api, get the response.

I am not sure if this is the perfect way, but this might be one way to do it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

one simple way is using the onChangeText event (described here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchangetext) and look for a spacebar on the last position of the string